# Find the position of lastIndexOf a List that start with a certain character in kotlin/Java

Tags: java, kotlin

```
var list_a = listOf("00:00",  "09:00", "20:00", "23:00", "01:00", "03:00") 

// i want to return the position of "23:00" in list_a

var list_b = listOf("00:10",  "00:30", "09:00", "21:10") 

// i want to return the position of "21:10" in list_b
```

How do I write a function to get the position of starting with 2X:XX?

How can I mix `lastIndexOf()` and `startsWith()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use normal `for-loops`, i.e.

```
int getIndexOfLastStringStartingWith2(List<String> list) {
   for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      if (list.get(i).startsWith("2")) {
        return i;
      }
   }

  return -1; 
}
```

This will return the index of the last string in the list starting with `2`.

Answer (score 2):

To find the last matching index of an item for any condition, use `indexOfLast` extension function of the list.

```
list_b.indexOfLast {
    it.startsWith("2")
}
```

---

To find the last item in the list, a more idiomatic approach would be to use methods provided by Kotlin, rather than making a new method.

```
list_b.findLast {
    it.startsWith("2")
}
```

This would return the last item that starts with `2` or null if it's not in the list. If you don't want it to return `null`, you can use the `Elvis` operator.

```
list_b.findLast {
    it.startsWith("2")
} ?: ""
```

This would return an empty `string` if no item is found.

Comment: You haven't actually answered the question (the OP was asking for the _index_, not the object) but your answer is probably more useful as the OP is probably interested in the object rather than the index.

Comment: @k314159 Thanks for notifying this, I misread the question that OP wants to find the last item, not the index. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin u can use `indexOfLast` function which returns index of the last element matching the given predicate, or -1 if the array does not contain such element.

```
list.indexOfLast {  
  it.startsWith("2")
}
```